# Input value returning empty strings to MySQL due to Javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, mysql, flask

I am trying to build an event manager that stores and retrieves data in MySQL.

Currently I am able to send input values to MySQL using Flask, however these values are empty strings.

I did some checking and found that the problem arises when I attach the input tag (type = 'submit') with an id = 'addButton'.

This links the input tag with the jQuery code and returns empty strings. When I remove the id attribute, the HTML is able to send non-empty strings.

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel = 'stylesheet' href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <title>Events and Opportunities</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = 'container'>
        <h1>Events and Opportunities</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr id = 'tableHeader'>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <form action = '/' method = 'POST' id = 'dataForm'>
                    <tr id = 'tableInput'>
                        <td><input type = 'date' name = 'dataDate' id = 'inputDate'></td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'dataCategory' id = 'inputCategory' maxlength = '20'></td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'dataTitle' id = 'inputTitle' maxlength = '100'></td>
                        <td><input type = 'text' name = 'dataDescription' id = 'inputDescription' maxlength = '500'></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Add" id = 'addButton' class="btn btn-default"></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src = 'static/app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript/ jQuery:

```
$('#addButton').on('click', () => {
    if ($('#inputDate').val() === '' || $('#inputCategory') === '' || $('#inputTitle') === '' || $('#inputDescription') === ''){
        alert('Please fill in the form.');
    }
    else{
        const valDate = $('<th></th>').text($('#inputDate').val());
        const valCategory = $('<th></th>').text($('#inputCategory').val());
        const valTitle = $('<th></th>').text($('#inputTitle').val());
        const valDescription = $('<th></th>').text($('#inputDescription').val());

        const newRow = $('<tr></tr>').append(valDate, valCategory, valTitle, valDescription);
        $('#tableInput').before(newRow);

        $('#inputDate').val('');
        $('#inputCategory').val('');
        $('#inputTitle').val('');
        $('#inputDescription').val('');
    }
})
```

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='yunani', host='127.0.0.1',  database='test')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date = request.form['dataDate']
        category = request.form['dataCategory']
        title = request.form['dataTitle']
        description = request.form['dataDescription']

        queryInsert = "INSERT INTO data (Category, Title, Description) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}')".format(category, title, description)
        cursor.execute(queryInsert)
        cnx.commit()
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: Change the button type to be **"button"** because you want the JavaScript to do the submit.

Comment: I changed the type to 'button', I also added a $('#dataForm').submit() to the jQuery in order to submit the form via the button click. However I am still receiving empty strings in my MySQL database.

Comment: I think that is because your script that runs before the POST is turning every form input to empty strings. Just do a `.serialize()` on the form and send the form data through jQuery.